# C# MVC Can't load partial view in Bootstrap tab

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I can't get partial views to load at all. I am trying to have a partial view load from a controller action for a section of my index view but the code's not doing anything. It's not even erroring or triggering any functions in the controller. This is my relevant code so far

HomeController.cs

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        
        [HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult PartialBlock()
        {
            var dataItems = _db.Data
                .OrderBy(t => t.Title)
                .ToList();

            return PartialView("_PartialBlock", dataItems);
        }
```

Views/Home/Index.cshtml

```
<div id="partialViewContainer"  class="card-deck">
  <div class="row">
    <a id="loadView" asp-action="PartialBlock"></a>;  
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#loadView').on('load', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET"
        url: '/Home/PartialBlock',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#partialViewContainer').html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Views/Home/PartialBlock.cshtml

```
@model List<Data>

@foreach (var dataitem in Model)
{
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">@dataitem.Title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">@dataitem.Info</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">More Text</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: You have route mapped for url `Home/Featured` to `PartialBlock()` action? If not then you should use `Home\PartialBlock`

Comment: Oh sorry that's my bad, I modified the code snippet to change it from the original for security reasons. Let me edit that in my post to fix that.

Comment: Should the name of this file: Views/Home/PartialBlock.cshtml be Views/Home/_PartialBlock.cshtml ? (leading underscore before partial view name)

Comment: @Roger sorry I copied it over wrong, yes it should be Views/Home/_PartialBlock.cshtml thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> $('#loadView').on('load', function() {

This method cannot trigger load correctly. You can use jQuery's load method：

```
$('#loadView').load('/Home/PartialBlock', function (data) {
       $('#partialViewContainer').html(data);
 })
```